# "undefined variable" warning, yet variable is defined in all processes

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, mpi, exit-code

EDIT: Newest code posted, down to one last warning... warning is stating that at line 97 "recvbuffer" (in the MPI_Send) is not defined... Yet I define recvbuffer[totalnums] in all processes prior to this point.  Why is the program not keeping the recvbuffer array variable I've defined when I get to the mergesort part of the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#define TAG 25


int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {                     /* Comparison function for qsort */
    int var1, var2, ret;
    var1 = *(const int *)a;
    var2 = *(const int *)b;
    if (var1 == var2) {
        ret = 0;
    }
    else {
        ret = (var1 < var2) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return ret;
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int rank, process;                              /* Variable declarations */

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);                             /* Initialize MPI */
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &process);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    int size, origsize, h, i, j, k, p, q, r, s, v, x, z, chunk;         /* Variable declarations */
    int totalnums;                                  /* Variable declarations */

    if (rank != 0) {                                /* Receive totalnums value from process 0 for all processes */
        MPI_Recv(&totalnums, 1, MPI_INT, 0, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        int recvbuffer[totalnums];                      /* Create recvbuffer array for all processes except root */
        qsort(recvbuffer, chunk, sizeof(int), compare);
    }

    if (rank == 0) {

        FILE *infilename;                           /* Initialize input file variable */

        infilename = fopen(argv[1], "r");                   /* Read input file */

        if (infilename == 0) {                          /* Check whether read-in file exists */
            printf("File not found.\n");
            return 1;
        }

        fscanf(infilename, "%d", &size);                    /* Obtain total number of items in file */

        totalnums = size;

        while (totalnums % process != 0) {                  /* Obtain total number of spots to allocate in array */
            totalnums += 1;
        }


        int A[totalnums];                           /* Declare array size */

        for (i = 0; i<size; i++) {                      /* Create array A[] from file using process 0 until end of file reached*/
            fscanf(infilename, "%d", &A[i]);
        }

        origsize = size;                            /* Store original value for total numbers in file */

        for (x = size; x < totalnums; x++) {                    /* Fill in empty spots at end of array with INT_MAX numbers */
            A[x] = INT_MAX;
        }

        fclose(infilename);                         /* Close the incoming file */

        MPI_Bcast(&origsize, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);            /* Broadcast origsize and send totalnums to all processes */
        for (h = 1; h < process; h++) {
            MPI_Send(&totalnums, 1, MPI_INT, h, TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }

        int recvbuffer[totalnums];                      /* Create recvbuffer array in process 0 */

        chunk = totalnums/process;                      /* Calculate chunk size for each process */

        MPI_Scatter(A, chunk, MPI_INT, recvbuffer, chunk, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);                  /* Send select chunk to each process */
        qsort(recvbuffer, chunk, sizeof(int), compare);             /* Perform sort on each chunk in individual processes */
    }

    int step, mergebuffer[totalnums], combinedbuffer[totalnums];            /* Create step and mergebuffer array variables */

    printf("stage 2 complete.\n");

    for (z = 0; z <= ((process-1)/2); z++) {                    /* Start mergesort */
        for (step = 1; step < process; step = 2*step) {
            if (rank % (2*(2 << z)*step) != 0) {
                MPI_Send(recvbuffer, (2 << z)*chunk, MPI_INT, rank-(step*(2 << z)), TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD);       /* Send elements to partner process */
                break;
            }
            else {
                MPI_Recv(mergebuffer, (2 << z)*chunk, MPI_INT, rank+(step*(2 << z)), TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);   /* Receive elements from partner process and store in mergebuffer */
                p = 0;
                q = 0;
                r = 0;
                while (p != (2 << z)*chunk && q != (2 << z)*chunk) {                    /* Start combining and sorting buffers */
                    if (recvbuffer[p] > mergebuffer[q] || q == (2 << z)*chunk) {
                        combinedbuffer[r] = recvbuffer[p];
                        r++;
                        p++;
                    }
                    else if (recvbuffer[p] <= mergebuffer[q] || p == (2 << z)*chunk) {
                        combinedbuffer[r] = mergebuffer[q];
                        r++;
                        q++;
                    }
                }
                v = 0;
                while (v != (2 << z)*chunk) {                           /* Copy combinedbuffer into recvbuffer to start next iteration */
                    recvbuffer[v] = combinedbuffer[v];
                }
            }
        }
        printf("get to here?\n");
    }

    if (rank == 0) {

        FILE *outfilename;                          /* Initialize output file variable */
        outfilename = fopen(argv[2], "w");                  /* Create output file */

        fprintf(outfilename, "Sorted array of %d elements:\n", origsize);   /* Print first line of output file */
        s = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < (totalnums/10); j++) {                  /* Create multiple rows of 10 numbers per row */
            for (k = 0; k < 10; k++) {                  /* Cycle 10 times */
                if (recvbuffer[s] != INT_MAX) {             /* Print next number to file until first INT_MAX entry reached */
                    fprintf(outfilename, "%d  ", recvbuffer[s]);
                }
                s++;                        /* Increase value to proceed through entire list */
            }
            fprintf(outfilename, "\n\n");                   /* Print two returns at end of each 10 number row */
        }
        fclose(outfilename);                            /* Close the outgoing file */

    printf("Stage 4 complete.\n");
    }

    MPI_Finalize();                                 /* Finalize MPI */

    printf("\n");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Learn how to use the debugger; the investment will pay off handsomely.

Comment: Even without a debugger, you can find the line that is causing the fault by inserting `printf()` cues. Divide and conquer: start in the middle, eliminate one half or the other, etc.

Comment: Which rank segfaults?

Comment: Thanks for the idea of the printf() statements.  I have found my first troublesome area.  Something is wrong with my MPI_Bcast statements, but not sure what the error is...

Comment: This code does not even come close to compiling. numerous warnings and a couple errors are in the posted code
when compiling, enable all the warnings. (in gcc, use something like -Wall -Wextra -W  -pedantic) In the code, always check the returned values (for instance from fscanf, fopen, the MPI functions to assure the operation was successful .  SWhen it actually/cleanly compiles, then use a debugger, for instance GDB (compile and link with the '-ggdb' parameter for best results)

Comment: What is this "warning" and where is line 97? You should post the exact error message after the code sample; and indicate the line by putting a comment in the code saying "this is line 97" or similar.

Comment: You've made the code even worse than it was originally by throwing `int recvbuffer[totalnums];` around. Each time you write that, it is declaring a different buffer\. The first time you do it (inside `if (rank != 0)`) you are calling `qsort` on an uninitialized buffer. The other instances of it have similar problems.

Comment: Ok thanks. Since it's my very first program in c, would you mind offering a suggestion to fix the issue? How would you go about it? I need the recvbuffer array in all processes, I can't declare it locally in each process and then either send or broadcast to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your comment that there is a problem with `MPI_Bcast`. You are calling this function three times.

```
int MPI_Bcast(void *buffer, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int root, MPI_Comm comm)
```

The first argument takes the *address* of a buffer. The last of your three calls is this

```
MPI_Bcast(recvbuffer, totalnums, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

which looks pretty good because you pass the buffer (and implicitly its address), and its size. But your first two calls are

```
MPI_Bcast(origsize, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(totalnums, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

In both these cases you are passing a buffer with 1 element, but you are not passing the buffer *address*. Although I don't fully follow your code I suggest trying this:

```
MPI_Bcast(&origsize, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(&totalnums, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Note the added `&` to indicate address. In the first statement, you passed an array, so its address is implicit in the statement, not so for a single integer.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I had added the "&" to all of the strings and it seemed to work ok up through that point (checked using printf's).  But your way of using the original "recvbuffer" as it was worked as well.  Thanks a lot!  I'm also receiving an error about "looking for (int), received (int *)" at lines 114 and 119 - at the end of the code where I am printing to the outfile.  Any ideas?  Do I remove the "&" in line 115?  What about attempting to print the "\n\n" (double returns)?  Is there another way to do this, or could I be getting an error from somewhere else carried to this point?

Comment: Should not use `&` in `fprintf(outfilename, "Sorted array of %d elements:\n", &origsize);` or  when printing `recvbuffer[s]`. Although why you are using `int origsize` and `int totalnums` for `MPI_Bcast()` etc, like this is beyond me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I did remove the & in front of recvbuffer, but did not see the other one you mentioned.  For some reason the warning line numbers were not lining up with the locations in the code.  Looking much better now, only 3 to 4 warnings to sort out.  Not bad I don't think for my first C program constructed :)  Thanks again for all your help!